# Double light switch issue

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light

[image][image]We have just wired a new 2 way, 2 gang, switch plate, which works, but for one side the 'on' position is up, and for the other it's down, which looks odd and is impractical. Is this a problem with the new switch itself, or something we've done wrong? (These switches are the only ones that control these 2 lights)

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the switch and box?

Comment: Can you reverse/rotate the weird switches?

Comment: Thanks - It's not letting me upload my image unfortunately. Sorry, not sure what you mean by 'reverse/rotate the switches.' It's a plastic plate with brass toggle switches- i wouldnt know how to go about dismantling the mechanism itself and trying to rotate the toggles, if that's what you mean.

Comment: The switch itself may be upside down. Before you attached the wires and mounted it, it would have been separate from the wall, turn it around (like literally, flip it the other way around) and screw it back to the plate "the other way". It should be held down with two screws. Also, please tell us, when you wired these in, did you SCREW the wires down or stick the wires into holes (called backstabs)? You should use the screw terminals or screw locks over plug-n-pray

Comment: @noybman  Plug-n-pray ....  I like that!!

Comment: Do the switches have the words on" and off" on them?  Are they made to be both 1-way and 2-way UK=3-way US? Try emailing the photo to yourself, and watch for an option to decide photo size.  Choose "medium" or a size under 1.9MB if it tells you that.  Then, aread your email and add the new photo to your phone/gallery.  Then, pick that one to post.

Comment: @Jack yes, I take my hat off!

Comment: Yes, they were screwed in. Surely if i flipped it, the problem would remain, just in reverse. The issue is that the two toggles ( it is a plastic switch plate with brass toggles) dont match. When both lights are off, one toggle is facing up and the other is facing down.

Comment: so the switches are a single unit, not two separate switches. What country are you in?

Comment: have added pic of outside, inside of box to follow. am in uk. no, they are not labelled on/off

Comment: so to clarify, in the picture, both lights are off, but toggles are in opposite positions as you can see.

Comment: someone on another site said i should "swap the lines of the one i want to reverse". At present, the two wires for each switch are plugged into 'com' (C) and '11' (L1). Is he suggesting I put one of the wires into 22 (L2) instead (the only other place it could go) and is this correct, and safe?

Answer (score 2):

### Flip one side from L1 to L2

Your switches are intended for both single-pole and multi-way (multi-location) applications; as a result, both the "up" and the "down" positions on the switch connect COM to another terminal (either L1 or L2, depending on which position we're talking about), instead of having only one position that connects the terminals together, with the other position leaving them open-circuited.

So, fixing this is simple: turn the breaker off at the distribution board, switch one of the wires on L1 to the L2 terminal for that switch (not the other switch's L2!), button the box up, turn the breaker back on at the distribution board, and enjoy your light switches!

Comment: Indeed @ThreePhaseEel, at first I assumed this was a standard 120V US style setup, now it is all clear!!! BTW to OP, those pictures are great!

Comment: Thank you everyone! @ThreePhaseEel, your solution worked :-)